# Convert : to comma separated value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I came across a row which has multiple values separated by a colon (:).
SQL considers the values to be one and throws an error" Cannot fine the requested Privilege". Example of the row shown below.

```
Servername  Instancename    Databasename Environment userid      access
ITSUSMPW01430   ITSUSMPW01430   ALL        DEV       userid SYSADMIN:SERVERADMIN
```

Here 2 roles are requested seperated by :
Need some assistance on how can we make SQL consider the values different?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could also differentiate them

```
SELECT Servername,
       Instancename,
       Databasename,
       Environment,
       userid,
       a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [access]
FROM
(
    SELECT Servername,
           Instancename,
           Databasename,
           Environment,
           userid,
           CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(access, ':', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS access 
    FROM <table>
) A
CROSS APPLY access.nodes('/A') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
Servername      Instancename    Databasename Environment userid   access
ITSUSMPW01430   ITSUSMPW01430   ALL        DEV          userid      SYSADMIN
ITSUSMPW01430   ITSUSMPW01430   ALL        DEV          userid      SERVERADMIN
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix the data structure.  Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea.  Instead, you should have a table, with one row per instance and access (assuming `instance` is the right entity).

Sometimes you are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  For merely searching for a single value, you can use `like`:

```
where ':'  + access + ':' like '%:' + 'SERVERADMIN' + ':%'
```

Such a query cannot take advantage of an index and is limited in optimization options.  The real solution is to create the second table, as described above.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is actually updated from a webpage where we allow users to select more than 1 Server role temporarily based on their business requirement. As per the example shown above, the user has selected 2 roles and that gets updated in a single column differentiated by a : . I don't have an option in the application to either store the 2nd role in a new row. Hence I wanted to know if there is any query to select the roles one by one and gran them automatically. The code mentioned above is not working for the example shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by modifying the below code.

```
where ':'  + access + ':' like '%:' + 'SERVERADMIN' + ':%'
```

Since we need to differentiate the roles seperated by : in the same column, I used the below query and it worked successfully for 2 as well as more values.

```
select access from table1 where access like '%:' and access like ':%';
```

Thank you Gordon for the pseudo code.